# SceneKitで作成した、立方体ジオメトリの各面タップ時に別々に画面遷移させたい！

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift4

プログラミング初心者で、swiftで開発を始めた者です。
SceneKitを使い、ジェスチャーで回転可能な、立方体のジオメトリを作成しました。

次に、この立方体の各面をタップした時に別のViewControllerに画面遷移させたいのですが、方法が分からず、困っています。

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit


class KuruKuruViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = GameScene() //適用するsceneを設定する


    // SCNView 設定
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    scnView.scene = scene
    scnView.showsStatistics = true 
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true 

    // CUBEジオメトリ
    let CUBE:SCNGeometry = SCNBox(width: 3, height: 3, length: 3, chamferRadius: 0.4)
    let geometryNode = SCNNode(geometry: CUBE)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(geometryNode) 
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

追記１　SCNHitTestResultのfaceIndexプロパティを使い画面遷移を試みたが、faceIndexが返す値を「各面に0~5の値が割り当てられている」と間違える。

```
@objc func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    let p = gestureRecognize.location(in: scnView) //pにタップした座標を渡す
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: [:]) //hitTestでタップした箇所のオブジェクトを検索
    var hitfaceIndex = (hitResults.first)?.faceIndex //初めにヒットしたオブジェクトの面のインデックスを返す

        if hitfaceIndex == 0 {
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue1", sender: nil)
        }
        if hitfaceIndex == 1 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue2", sender: nil)
        }
        if hitfaceIndex == 2 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue3", sender: nil)
        }
        if hitfaceIndex == 3 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue4", sender: nil)
        }
        if hitfaceIndex == 4 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue5", sender: nil)
        }
        if hitfaceIndex == 5 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue6", sender: nil)
        }

 }
```

追記２ faceIndexが返す値を調べる為にprintを使ってシュミレータで画面タップした時に値を表示するようにした。結果、各面に0と1の値が表示された。(chamferRadiusが0の場合)
各面で値が被るため、個別の画面遷移が出来ない。

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit


class KuruKuruViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = GameScene()

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    scnView.scene = scene
    scnView.showsStatistics = true
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

    let CUBE:SCNGeometry = SCNBox(width: 3, height: 3, length: 3, chamferRadius: 0.0)
    let geometryNode = SCNNode(geometry: CUBE)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(geometryNode)

    //各面毎にマテリアルを設定するためにマテリアル情報を準備
    let m1 = SCNMaterial()
    let m2 = SCNMaterial()
    let m3 = SCNMaterial()
    let m4 = SCNMaterial()
    let m5 = SCNMaterial()
    let m6 = SCNMaterial()

    //マテリアルにイメージを設定
    m1.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "1")
    m2.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "2")
    m3.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "3")
    m4.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "4")
    m5.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "5")
    m6.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "6")

    //CUBEの各面のマテリアルに設定
    CUBE.materials = [m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6]

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture) 

}

//CUBEの面をタップするとfaceIndexの値をprintする
@objc func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    let p = gestureRecognize.location(in: scnView)
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: [:]) 
    if let number = hitResults.first?.faceIndex {
        print(number)
    }

 }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

追記３( 解決 )　`SCNGeometry`に対して複数の`SCNMaterial`を設定した場合、同時に`SCNGeometryElement`も複数になり、`SCNHitTestResult`のプロパティ`faceIndex`では、各面0と1の値しか返さない事が判明した。
そこで、同じ`SCNHitTestResult`のプロパティである`geometryIndex`を使ったところ、各面の値を取得することが出来た。
そして、画面遷移のコードに取得した値を割り当てて、「立方体ジオメトリの各面タップ時に別々に画面遷移する」ことに成功した。

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class KuruKuruViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = GameScene() //適用するsceneを設定する

    // SCNView 設定
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    scnView.scene = scene
    scnView.showsStatistics = true //統計情報を表示
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true  //ジェスチャーで様々なカメラ操作を可能に

    // CUBEジオメトリ
    let CUBE:SCNGeometry = SCNBox(width: 3, height: 3, length: 3, chamferRadius: 0.0)
    let geometryNode = SCNNode(geometry: CUBE)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(geometryNode) //チルドノードをルートノードに適応

    //各面毎にマテリアルを設定するためにマテリアル情報を準備
    let m1 = SCNMaterial()
    let m2 = SCNMaterial()
    let m3 = SCNMaterial()
    let m4 = SCNMaterial()
    let m5 = SCNMaterial()
    let m6 = SCNMaterial()

    //マテリアルにイメージを設定
    m1.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "1")
    m2.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "2")
    m3.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "3")
    m4.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "4")
    m5.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "5")
    m6.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "6")

    //CUBEの各面のマテリアルに設定
    CUBE.materials = [m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6]

    //タップジェスチャーを追加
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture) //viewをタップするとタップジェスチャーを追加 handleTap関数を実行

}

//<CUBE全体タップ>タップで画面遷移 handleTap関数を設定
@objc func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    let p = gestureRecognize.location(in: scnView)
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: [:])
    let number = hitResults.first?.geometryIndex  // ジオメトリのエレメントの値を取得

        //画面遷移
        if number == 0 {
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue1", sender: nil)
        }
        if number == 1 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue2", sender: nil)
        }
        if number == 2 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue3", sender: nil)
        }
        if number == 3 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue4", sender: nil)
        }
        if number == 4 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue5", sender: nil)
        }
        if number == 5 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue6", sender: nil)
        }

 }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

Comment: `SCNHitTestResult`のプロパティ`faceIndex`を使ってみてはいかがですか？

Comment: @nagonsoftware  返答有り難うございます。faceIndexプロパティを使ってみましたが、各面毎に画面遷移出来ません。確認していただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*追記1に対して：*

引用プログラムコード中の、プロパティ`faceIndex`に関連するコメント行として、「//初めにヒットしたオブジェクトの面のインデックスを返す」と書いていらっしゃいますが、この「オブジェクトの面」とは、なにを指しているのでしょうか？その考察をどうやら質問者さんはなさっていないようで、この考察をしなければ、解決するものも解決しないままとなってしまいます。
変更後のコードをすこし形を変えて、`faceIndex`と「オブジェクトの面」を調べるプログラムにしてみましょう。

```
@objc func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    let p = gestureRecognize.location(in: scnView)
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: [:])
    if let number = hitResults.first?.faceIndex {
        print(number)
    }
}
```

Xcodeのプロジェクトから、シミュレータないし実機を起動し、Xcodeのコンソールに、`print()`関数から出力される`faceIndex`の値を、立方体の上をあちこちタップして調べてください。
立方体`SCNBox`の`chamferRadius`を`0`すなわち角を丸めない状態だと、下図のような結果になります。下図は立方体を展開したものです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

立方体を、三角形ポリゴンで分割した各面の番号が、`faceIndex`であることがわかります。

※`chamferRadius`を`0`より大きくして角を丸くすると、総ポリゴン数が増えるので、立方体の面を構成するポリゴンの番号は、変化します。

---

*ご質問の追記2に対して：*

ひとつのジオメトリ（`SCNGeometry`）に対して、複数のマテリアル（`SCNMaterial`）を設定すると、「各面に0と1の値が表示」されることになるようです。これは、同時にエレメント（`SCNGeometryElement`）も複数になるということが推論できます。SceneKitフレームワークのリファレンスを読んでも、そのようなことを書いている箇所を見つけられないので、わかりにくいのですが、もしこの推論が間違っていなければ、`SCNHitTestResult`のプロパティ`geometryIndex`を使えば、立方体の各面がそれぞれ別個のエレメントになっているはずなので、面の識別ができることになります。
「追記1に対して：」のサンプルコードを次のように書き換えてみました。

```
@objc func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    let p = gestureRecognize.location(in: scnView)
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: [:])
    if let number = hitResults.first?.geometryIndex { //変更
        print(number)
    }
}
```

これで各面の識別ができるか、ご確認ください。

Comment: 丁寧な回答有り難うございます。立方体の各面に0~5の番号が割り振られているものと思い込んでいました。今後は調べるように注意します。　上記の方法で、faceIndexの値を調べてみましたが、表示されるのは0~11の番号ではなく、各面0と1の番号で、それが6面存在する。という状態でした。これだとfaceIndexの番号が被っているため、画面遷移を別々に割り当てることは出来ません。何か方法があればご教授いただけないでしょうか？自分で調べた限りでは有効な方法を見つけることが出来ませんでした。

Comment: その「上記の方法で、faceIndexの値を調べてみましたが、表示されるのは0~11の番号ではなく、各面0と1の番号で、それが6面存在する。という状態でした。」という現象が発生するソースコードを示してください。現在質問者さんが提示しているコードでは、そのようになりません。`faceIndex`の値は、0,1,50,51,100,101,150,151,200,201,250,251が出力されます。

Comment: chamferRadiusを0にした結果をコメントしていました。誤解を招き申し訳有りませんでした。現在のコードを質問文に追記しますが、やはり各面0と1の番号しか表示されません。そういう仕様ではなく何か原因があるのでしょうか。

Comment: @mota 回答を追加しました。

Comment: 2日前回答いただいたコードで確認したところ、各面別々(0~5)の値が得られ、無事解決致しました。最終的なコードを追記しました。どうも有難うございました。

Comment: @nagonsoftware上のコメントの"2日前"はミスです。お気になさらないで下さい。